# Best way to handle events in ecommerce store

Tags: event-handling, rabbitmq, mq, webhooks, business-process-management

I have the ecommerce store.

I faced automatization problems as my business growing.

My website is written in PHP on **Kohana Framework**.

**I want to automize many processes, but do not know where to dig deeper.**

**Example**:

When order is recieved I want to fire the event "order.recieved". This event knows that my system needs to fire subevents and other actions:

- to log inventrory changes asynchronously;
- send to the procurement module out-of-stock products and their quantity;
- to recreate sliced inventory table asynchronously;
- send real-time message to crm system that order is recieved;
- send sms to the client with message "We will call you soon";
- etc.

**Solutions I have in my head:**

1) I think the simplest way is to rewrite my application on Laravel framework with it's event dispatcher.

*Challenges*:

- I want use fifo (First In, First Out) for the inventory change;
- I need digging to the code to know how many events I have in my system, when they are used,

2) Use AMQP Middleware like RabbitMQ.

*Challenges*:

- I need digging to the code to know where exactly message is sent;
- Maybe It can be solved with some event dispatcher, but ->;
- Again, I need digging to the code to know how many events I have in my system, when they are used

Are php workers/consumers good to handle messages? Or I need to use python, nodejs?

*Challenges*:

- I need to have many php workers/consumers. I think PHP is not good to handle this.

3) Use some webhooks management system.

4) Study more and use some bpm engine. Only one thing I know right now I can benefit using business rule engine for complex discounts.

What solution I need to take and get deeper with it?

Comment: Would be pretty easy to use laravel for that, but I would count that as a valid solution if you need to rewrite all you code only because of that

Comment: Wouldnt*. Sorry for typo